# C# DataGrid cell values from selected row

Tags: c#, wpf

In my sample app I used ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

Here is my code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InventoryEntities context;
    context = new Inventory.InventoryEntities();
    var query = from x in context.Artikli
                select new { x.ID, x.Sifra, x.Naziv, x.Kolicina, x.Prodajna, x.Nabavna, x.UkupnoProdajna, x.UkupnoNabavna, x.Slika };
    var results = query.ToList();
    grdArtikli.ItemsSource = results;
}

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Artikli mojID = (Artikli)grdArtikli.Items[grdArtikli.SelectedIndex];//This line raises error
    MessageBox.Show(mojID.ID.ToString());

}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Inventory.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Inventory"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1600" ResizeMode="NoResize" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="790" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1590">
            <TabControl.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF1A36E8"/>
            </TabControl.Effect>
            <TabItem Header="Artikli" Width="70" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold">
                <TabItem.Background>
                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.8"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF00E2FF" Offset="1"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </TabItem.Background>
                <Grid Background="#FFACC383">
                    <DataGrid x:Name="grdArtikli" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1550" Height="650" Background="#FF78B6EC" BorderBrush="#FF72DA36" Foreground="#FFB91313" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" MouseDoubleClick="grdArtikli_MouseDoubleClick" SelectionChanged="grdArtikli_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedIndex="0">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="80" Binding="{Binding ID}" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Binding="{Binding Sifra}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Šifra" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="250" Binding="{Binding Naziv}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Naziv" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Binding="{Binding Kolicina}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Količina" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="150" Binding="{Binding Prodajna}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Prodajna Cena" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="150" Binding="{Binding Nabavna}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Nabavna Cena" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="150" Binding="{Binding UkupnoProdajna}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Sum Prodajna" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="150" Binding="{Binding UkupnoNabavna}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Sum Nabavna" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Slika" Width="*">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Slika}" Stretch="Fill" Width="Auto" Height="30" x:Name="mojaSlika" Loaded="mojaSlika_Loaded">

                                        </Image>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGrid.DataContext>
                            <local:Artikli Naziv="0" Sifra="0" UkupnoNabavna="0" UkupnoProdajna="0"/>
                        </DataGrid.DataContext>

                    </DataGrid>
                    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="423,693,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In button_click event in the line: `Artikli mojID = (Artikli)grdArtikli.Items[grdArtikli.SelectedIndex];` I get the InvalidCastException:

> Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`9[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.Single,System.Single,System.Nullable`1[System.Single],System.Nullable`1[System.Single],System.Byte[]]' to type 'Inventory.Artikli'

What is wrong?

Comment: Set breakpoint on that line and look what is inside `grdArtikli.Items`.

Comment: Working with data out your ui is a bad idea. You should take a look at mvvm. Bind the selecteditem to a property in a window viewmodel and work with that. I would also recommend translating model data to a viewmodel ( and back ) rather than directly exposing a model to the view. You then have somewhere discrete to put any validation logic, extra properties necessary for the view etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line :

```
select new { x.ID, x.Sifra, x.Naziv, x.Kolicina, x.Prodajna, x.Nabavna, x.UkupnoProdajna, x.UkupnoNabavna, x.Slika };
```

Is returning an anonymous object containing those fields, that is what is in the list. Change this to instantiate a class instead, or do not project the item to something else.

For example, try:

```
context.Artikli.ToList()
```

instead of the Linq.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is

```
var query = from x in context.Artikli
                select new { x.ID, x.Sifra, x.Naziv, x.Kolicina, x.Prodajna, x.Nabavna, x.UkupnoProdajna, x.UkupnoNabavna, x.Slika };
```

This is an anonymous type, which you are then try to cast back into type Artikli.
If you remove the New and the specific fields from the query, (you may have to tweak the bindings) this will allow you to cast it back again.